# Split zip code in a column into 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

This is what my end result should look like.  If there is not the four digits to move over to the second column then fill with 4 zeros.

How can I split zip code in a column into 2 columns and fill empty cells in column 2 if first column has only 5 digits?

[image: this should be end result]

Here is what I have been working with

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")

For Each cell In ws.Range("K2:K500").Cells
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(cell.Value, 5)
Next cell
   
Dim cel As Range, rngC As Range, rngB As Range
Dim lastRowA As Long, lastRowB As Long

With ws
    lastRowK = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row 'last row of column A
    lastRowL = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row 'last row of column B
    For Each cel In .Range("K2:K" & lastRowL)   'loop through column L
        'check if cell in column A exists in column B
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("K2:K" & lastRowL), cel) = 0 Then
            cel.Offset(0, 3).Value = Right(cel.Value, 4)
            '.Range("M" & cel.Row) = Right(cell.Value, 4)
        Else
            .Range("M" & cel.Row) = "0000"
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: please explain what your code is doing that is in errror.

Comment: Are you open to a formula solution?

Comment: Why VBA? This can be easily solved with a formula...

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest ways to solve this problem is to supplement the original string with a large number of zeros and take the values ​​of the first and second five characters for two cells:

```
Sub setZIPandZeros()
    Const TEN_ZEROS = "0000000000"    ' 10 times
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sLongString As String
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    For Each cell In ws.Range("K2:K" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        sLongString = Trim(cell.Text) & TEN_ZEROS
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(Left(sLongString, 5), _
            Mid(sLongString, 6, 5))
    Next cell
End Sub
```

**Update** The modified code is much faster and gives a result that more closely matches the description of the task:

```
Sub setZipZeros()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rResult As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Addressing R1C1 is used in the formulas - If the original range
    ' is shifted to another column, you will need to change the letter
    ' of the column "K" only in this line
    Set rResult = ws.Range("K2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 1)
    
    ' If the columns L:M are already in text format, then instead of
    ' the results we will get the texts of formulas
    rResult.Resize(, 2).NumberFormat = "General"
    
    ' These two lines do most of the work:
    rResult.Formula2R1C1 = "=LEFT(TRIM(RC[-1])&""00000"",5)"
    rResult.Offset(0, 1).Formula2R1C1 = "=MID(TRIM(RC[-2])&""000000000"",6,4)"
    
    ' We don't know if auto-recalculation mode is on now
    ' Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    Set rResult = rResult.Resize(, 2)
    
    ' Set the text format for the cells of the result
    ' to prevent conversions "00123" to "123"
    rResult.NumberFormat = "@"
    
    ' Replace formulas with their values
    rResult.Value = rResult.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: No need to loop. You can enter the formula in the entire range in one go. For example     `ws.Range("L2:L" & ws.Range("L" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=LEFT(K2,5)"` and then 
    `ws.Range("M2:M" & ws.Range("M" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=MID(K2&""000000000"", 6, 4)"` BTW, I think it should be Nine 0's and not ten 0's. Same thing can be achieved with a formula. `=LEFT(K2,5)` and then drag it down. Similarly `=MID(K2&"000000000", 6, 4)` :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for your comment. This would be useful if the macro would insert formulas. But the macro inserts values, the result of calculating formulas. It is very wasteful to store ​​in the workbook 1000 formulas for 500 values, which will never change (and ZIP codes change very rarely). 10 zeros are needed for empty cells, with nine zeros we will get an incomplete value in the second cell.

Comment: After the formula is put you can add one more line `ws.Range("L2:L" & ws.Range("L" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value = ws.Range("L2:L" & ws.Range("L" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value` This will convert formulas to values in 1 go for the entire column :) Also if you use 10 zeros then you will end up with Five 0's in 2nd column. OP wants 4 zeros.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, you are right - this solution is more elegant. I have updated my answer. However, one more problem remains: for very large strings of numbers, we will get a decimal separator in the second position of the result. For example, for 123456789012345000000, the macro will give 1,234 and 5678 instead of the expected 12345 and 6789

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to bypass VBA and use formulas, you can do this.

**Cell B2:**

```
    =LEFT(A2,5)
```

**Cell C2:**

```
    =IF(LEN(A2)=9,RIGHT(A2,4),"0000")
```

[image]